# ProgressBar: set the width of the pulse block

Tags: python, pygtk

Is there any way to change the width of the block which is moving on `gtk.ProgressBar.pulse()`?

Answer (score 0):

Not on PyGTK. If you are using GTK 3 then there is a CSS class, `GtkProgressBar:pulse`, but I can't find any documentation on how to change the width. It might be possible if you do some digging.